# Hoist result of IN clause as an attribute of a SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which presents a nested `WHERE..IN..SELECT`:

```
id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM item WHERE deleted = 0)
```

What I want to do is get the result of the `IN` operator into the `SELECT` attribute list, much like this:

```
SELECT id, ... AS ID_IS_IN_MAX
```

The `...` part is where the `TRUE` or `FALSE` is computed exactly how it is shown above.

Obviously, I don't want to burden the query too much, so I also wonder what the performance of such a solution would be.

One solution that came to my mind is a `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN ... THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

Would this work? What about performance?

Comment: You asked "what about performance" so perhaps that is important. You may want to test both answers (the one you accepted and the one I proposed) to see which works best on your data.

Comment: The problem is a tad worse, there's a bound variable so the overall complexity cannot go below what it is. My question was more about syntax without worsening above O(n*n) and not about optimization. Right now it runs with the cartesian product (`CROSS JOIN`). I thank you for the attention and time you dedicated. I upvoted your answer and would again, if I could. But the actual solution is what Maheswaran proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cross join. `MAX()` will return only one row, and it will not be impacting performance.

```
SELECT id,
  CASE
    WHEN id = max_id
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END
FROM your_table a
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM your_table WHERE deleted=0 ) b ;
```

Comment: Not sure about "will not be impacting performance". Finding the MAX requires going over the table once, and then the table needs to be read again for the join. The join itself will not impact performance, but the fact that the table needs to be read twice may.

Comment: Window functions are CPU intensive, and depending the number of rows it is going to cost more for OLTP queries running in parallel. And again it is totally based on the data below. Which is Good/Bad. And reading the table twice is definitely not bad. And for the matter of fact you missed the condition (`deleted = 0` for the `MAX`).

Comment: OK, two parts to that comment. First, thank you for pointing out that I misread the OP's requirement... the MAX is over a restricted set of rows but the output should show all the base rows, not just the restricted set. I missed that. I fixed it in the answer now (with proper credit). The other part: Not sure what you mean by "reading the table twice is definitely not bad." With a large table it is definitely bad - I/O operations typically (although not always) take much longer than whatever happens in memory or in the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

This is best solved with an analytic function, so that you don't read the base table more than once. Since you didn't post any test data, the solution below uses the EMP table in the SCOTT schema (standard on most Oracle installations) and EMPNO instead of ID, but otherwise it's the same problem.

**Edit**: Delete this paragraph from the original answer:  *Whatever filters (WHERE clause conditions) you need to add can come after the FROM clause.*

As Mareshwaran pointed out in a Comment to me under his Answer, I misinterpreted the OP's requirement. The comparison should be against the max over a subset; the WHERE clause does not apply to the outer SELECT, only to the definition of the MAX.

This can be solved with another CASE expression, within the analytic function. Again, using what exists in SCOTT.EMP, I will illustrate this using a condition of "where deptno = 20". This changes the output as well (what is shown below is different from the original query and the original output).

If instead the requirement is to mark "true" every EMPNO that is the highest in its own department, that can be done using `max(empno)`, with no case expression, `over(partition by deptno)`. Not part of the original question, but closely related (perhaps).

```
select empno, 
       case when empno = max(case when deptno = 20 then empno end) over () 
                                              then 'true' else 'false' end as is_max 
from   scott.emp;



 EMPNO IS_MAX
------ ------
  7369 false
  7499 false
  7521 false
  7566 false
  7654 false
  7698 false
  7782 false
  7788 false
  7839 false
  7844 false
  7876 false
  7900 false
  7902 true           -- marking highest EMPNO in department 20
  7934 false
```

Answer (score 1):

@Maheswaran Ravisankar is right.
Just another way

```
SELECT id, NVL2(max_id, 'true', 'false') AS id_is_in_max
  FROM your_table t1,
       (SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM your_table WHERE deleted = 0 ) t2
 WHERE t1.id = t2.max_id(+)
```